# How to auto run schedualing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, security

I'm new in Laravel and I need to swlwtw otps expired in my otps database, I create an expiration file and define all things, and the command runs perfectly when I use
`php artisan schedule:run`

this is the output:

```
2022-09-17 16:37:15 Running ['artisan' Otp:expire] in background .......................................... 7ms DONE
  ⇂ ('/usr/bin/php8.1' 'artisan' Otp:expire > '/dev/null' 2>&1 ; '/usr/bin/php8.1' 'artisan' schedule:finish "framework/schedule-7ff27dde37314470633aef84f65f27b83fd05b4e" "$?") > '/dev/null' 2>&1 &
```

but when I run the server with php artisan serve and I add an OTP the OTP didn't be deleted after the time expected, it deletes only when I use schedule run.
any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

The official laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler) suggests running the `php artisan schedule:run` command every minute by using a cron (Cronjob etc.). You can do it by using the following cron entry:

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Supervisor, which runs your command constantly, and when the process finishes the new one will start immediately.
If you use Cronjob, you should know that It runs every process for a minute minimum! Please check the Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#supervisor-configuration)